OAuth2 Authentication Code Grant with Spring Security OAuth2 Client
I'm trying to implement this architecture (OAuth2 Authorization Code Grant Flow). I want to implement the Client BFF with spring-security-oauth2-client.

So far step 0 and 1 work create. The SPA requests the BFF and BFF gets 403 from the Resource-Server and returns the authorisation-URI to the SPA. SPA requests the Authorization-Server and gets the Authorization-code. But I'm struggling with step 2, 3 and 4. I want to use Spring WebClient to access the resource-server. Here is my code:
configuration
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          printful:
            client-id: XXX
            client-secret: XXX
            client-authentication-method: none # because we are using a public client
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            redirect-uri: "{baseUrl}/authorized/printful"
        provider:
          printful:
            authorization-uri: https://www.printful.com/oauth/authorize
            token-uri: https://www.printful.com/oauth/token

security-config
@Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http.authorizeExchange(exchange -> exchange.anyExchange().permitAll())
                .oauth2Client(oauth2Login -> oauth2Login
                        .authorizationRequestResolver(
                                new DefaultServerOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver(clientRegistrationRepository))
                        )
                .anonymous(anonymousSpec -> anonymousSpec.principal("xxx"));
        return http.build();
    }

    private ServerOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver authorizationRequestResolver(
            ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository) {
        return new DefaultServerOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver(
                        clientRegistrationRepository);
    }

client-configuration (this code comes from any Baeldung tutorial, I could not explain why I do this :D )
@Configuration
public class PrintfulConfiguration {

    public static final String PRINTFUL_REGISTRATION_ID = "printful";

    @Bean
    public WebClient printfulWebClient(
            ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrations,
            ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClients,
            @Value("${printful.baseUrl}") String baseUrl) {

        ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth =
                new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(clientRegistrations, authorizedClients);
        oauth.setDefaultClientRegistrationId(PRINTFUL_REGISTRATION_ID);

        return WebClient.builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .filter(oauth)
                .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .build();
    }

}

controller
private final WebClient webClient;

@GetMapping("/stores")
public Mono<Stores> getPrintful(Authentication authentication) {
        return webClient.get()
                .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.pathSegment("stores").build())
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(Stores.class);

@PostMapping("/authorized/printful")
public Mono<String> authorized(@RequestBody Map<String, String> payload, Authentication authentication) {
    String authorizationCode = payload.get("code");
    String codeVerifier = payload.get("code_verifier");
    
    return authentication
                .map(auth -> OAuth2AuthorizeRequest.withClientRegistrationId("printful").principal(auth).build())
                .flatMap(authorizeRequest -> {
                            return authorizedClientManager.authorize(authorizeRequest); <-- Here is something wrong: authorizedRequest.authorizedClient is null and this triggers an exception and another 403 response...
                })
                .doOnNext(client -> {
                    log.info("Authorized client: {}", client);
                })
                .map(client -> ResponseEntity.ok().build());
}

My problem is, that the request to {baseUrl}/authorized/printful ends again in a 403 with an html body, even if I started the authentication flow over the angular frontend before.
My registeredClient Instance never reached the authenticatedClientsRepository, so spring won't do step 3 and get the Access Token and request the resource.
What am I missing?
